# Authorize.Net transactionType

Tags: authorize.net-cim

As authorize.net (CIM) provides the facility of charging a credit card. Along with that the method `createTransactionRequest` requires `transactionType` parameter. I know that different transaction types are

- AuthOnly
- AuthCapture
- CaptureOnly
- PriorAuthCapture
- Refund
- Void

I want to know what is the meaning of these types and how I can make use of all these types available through API.

Answer (score 0):

The abbreviations you list are defined CIM class properties:

```
private $_transactionTypes = array(
    'AuthOnly',
    'AuthCapture',
    'CaptureOnly',
    'PriorAuthCapture',
    'Refund',
    'Void',
);
```

See http://www.authorize.net/support/merchant/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm for definitions of each type. You pass the type as the first parameter in createCustomerProfileTransaction:

```
$transaction = new AuthorizeNetTransaction;
// add more elements to $transaction
$response = $request->createCustomerProfileTransaction("AuthCapture", $transaction);
```